# Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts Mac

Tags: macos, freeze, recover

The Mac has decided to freeze and restart several times a day while I'm using it.

```
panic (cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801a579938): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 93 seconds  .....
```

- Used the repair disk utility tool multiple times in different recovery modes.
- I Used every free admin fixing tool, clean up tool and error reporting tool on the app store.
- Launched my Mac in all sorts of different recovery modes. I literally pressed and used every restart keyboard combination you can with a Mac. And I used them several times over and over in different scenarios.
- Spent hours researching every forum and reading every article of similar problems and solutions.
- Download the manual updates and installed them each separately

Comment: This question belongs on [apple.se], as it is not programming related. SO is strictly for questions related to programming, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

After a day of frustration i found then solution

The fans internal sensor wasn’t working any more.
I set the automatic controls using **Macs Fan Control** app and in Custom switched to *Sensor-based value* and selected CPU PECI from drop down and set 30 in Temperature that the fan speed will start to increase from and 90 in Max temperature. Fans now kicking in and cooling down the processors and preventing from re-starting.

[Source](https://trxtraveller.com/finally-solved-mac-how-fix-could-not-recover-sata-hdd-after-5-attempts-terminating-error/)